# resizing boost::multi_array to match another

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I need to resize one multi_array to the size of another.

In Blitz++ I could just do

`arr1.resize(arr2.shape());`

Is there a multi_array solution of similar length? Because

`arr1.resize(boost::extents[arr2.shape()[0]][arr2.shape()[1]]);`

seems a little long and arduous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `shape()` member. Sadly  it cannot directly serve as an `ExtentList` (it doesn't model the `Collection` concept) but it's easy to make it into one:

```
using MA = multi_array<double, 2>;
MA ma(extents[12][34]);
auto& ma_shape = reinterpret_cast<boost::array<size_t, MA::dimensionality> const&>(*ma.shape());
```

So that

```
// demo
std::cout << "[" << ma_shape[0] << "][" << ma_shape[1] << "]\n";
```

Prints `[12][34]`.

Now, `ma_shape` can directly be used to reshape/resize another array:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5b5570384f2a80e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace boost;
    using MA = multi_array<double, 2>;

    MA ma(extents[12][34]);
    auto& ma_shape = reinterpret_cast<boost::array<size_t, MA::dimensionality> const&>(*ma.shape());

    // demo
    std::cout << "[" << ma_shape[0] << "][" << ma_shape[1] << "]\n";

    // resize
    MA other;
    assert(!std::equal(ma_shape.begin(), ma_shape.end(), other.shape()));

    other.resize(ma_shape);
    assert(std::equal(ma_shape.begin(), ma_shape.end(), other.shape()));

    // reshape
    other.resize(extents[1][12*34]);
    assert(!std::equal(ma_shape.begin(), ma_shape.end(), other.shape()));

    other.reshape(ma_shape);
    assert(std::equal(ma_shape.begin(), ma_shape.end(), other.shape()));
}
```

Comment: That looks like it will work. I am wrapping the multi_array, so I can just hide that stuff and keep all outside code the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is another oversight of Boost.MultiArray. I have written a bunch of "utility" functions that allows to take the shape (dimension sizes), base indices (e.g. 0 or 1 for each dimension) and extensions (base indices and sizes in each dimension).

```
namespace boost{
template<class MultiArray>
detail::multi_array::extent_gen<MultiArray::dimensionality>
extension(MultiArray const& ma){ //this function is adapted from 
    typedef detail::multi_array::extent_gen<MultiArray::dimensionality> gen_type;
    gen_type ret;
    typedef typename gen_type::range range_type;
    for(int i=0; i != MultiArray::dimensionality; ++i)
        ret.ranges_[i] = range_type(ma.index_bases()[i], ma.index_bases()[i]+ma.shape()[i]);
    return ret;
}
}
```

Which is later used as:

```
boost::multi::array<double, 3> m(boost::multi::extents[3][4][5]);
boost::multi::array<double, 3> n(extension(m)); // n takes the extension (and shape) of m
```

(If the base indexes are not zero it also works. It works also for view and other multi_array-type classes.)

Comment: @Cory, many years later I implemented a more ergonomic multidimensional array library, where you just do `arr1.reextent(arr2.extensions())`. https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi